# R.string cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I am programming a map in android, I follow this tutorial [hier](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html),and I want to add error messages, but the errors are not in R class. The errors, which I mean, are:
R.string.invalid_lat_long_used, R.string.service_not_available     R.string.no_address_found, R.string.address_found
how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: did you add these strings in `Strings.xml` file?

Comment: Rebuild/sync your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link that you followed, doesnt says about the changes that you have to make in other resource files.

The reason why you are not able to get `R.string.invalid_lat_long_used`,`R.string.service_not_available` etc are because, these are custom strings that are specified by you. So you'll have to declare these strings in a file named `Strings.xml` manually.

You can see that, there is already a file named `Strings.xml` in your project. So you'll have to edit the `Strings.xml` file with all the above mentioned Strings.

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicNetworking/res/values/strings.html), values in `Strings.xml` can be set as follows

```
<resources>
    <string name="test_text">Test</string>
    <string name="clear_text">Clear</string>
    <string name="wifi_connection">The active connection is wifi.</string>
    <string name="mobile_connection">The active connection is mobile.</string>
    <string name="no_wifi_or_mobile">No wireless or mobile connection.</string>
</resources>
```

So for your case the `Strings.xml` file should contain all these Strings too

```
<string name="invalid_lat_long_used">Invalid Lat Long</string>
<string name="service_not_available ">Service Not Available</string>
<string name="no_address_found">No address found</string>
<string name="address_found">Address found</string>
```

etc..

**`Strings.xml` file can be found inside `res / values /`**

Answer (score 0):

Add that values inside the `Strings.xml` file:

```
<string name="invalid_lat_long_used">Invalid Lat Long Used</string>
<string name="service_not_available ">Service Not Available</string>
<string name="no_address_found">No Address Found</string>
<string name="address_found">Address Found</string>
```